Flow of water through a paper/textile bridge
Problem: to passively (without the use of electronics) add water from one large reservoir of water ("barrel") to a smaller reservoir of water ("tank").
The tank evaporates water. I do not know how much water that is evaporating nor do I know when. I'd therefore want a solution that adds water passively.

My question is, what are the forces and/or reasons for the flow of water? How can I make the water flow go from the barrel to the tank? Do the levels between the starting points (h1, h2) affect the flow? How can I maximize the flow of water? Can I add more cloth in one end rather than the other?

See siphons https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siphon. Basically, a combined effect of pressure differential and cohesive force within the liquid, will work to transfer liquids between reservoirs
